# Sp(1) and SO(3) Locally Isomorphic - Trouble with part of proof

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

My apologies if this is fairly basic. I'm trying to understand the proof that $Sp(1)$ and $SO(3)$ are locally isomorphic but are not isomorphic but have run into some trouble. Here's what my understanding is so far:

Take $x\in Im\mathbb{H}$. Each $q\in Sp(1)$ defines a map:

$\rho(q):Im\mathbb{H} \rightarrow Im\mathbb{H}, \rho(q)(x)=qx\bar{q}$

We note that if $x\in Im\mathbb{H}$,then we write $x=bi+cj+dk$, and then $\bar{x}=-bi-cj-dk=-x$. So for purely imaginary quaternions, $\bar{x}=-x$. So $\rho(q)(x)\in Im\mathbb{H}$ if $x \in Im\mathbb{H}$.

For $q\in Sp(1)$, $|\rho(q)(x)|=|qx\bar{q}|=|q||x||\bar{q}|=|x|$ since $|q|=|\bar{q}|=1$. So $\rho(q) \in O(3)$ is orthogonal.

We can see that we have a homomorphism $\rho:Sp(1) \rightarrow O(3)$.

However, now the notes that I'm following say that this is actually a homomorphism $\rho:Sp(1) \rightarrow SO(3)$ and I can't quite see why. Is it because $Sp(1)$ is connected, and the connected component of the identity in $O(3)$ is $SO(3)$ or is it something else?

Many thanks for any responses.

Comment: if you know that $\rho$ is continuous and the groups you mentioned are connected, then yours is a perfectly good explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right. $Sp(1)$ can be identified with $S^3$, so it is connected. Your map $\rho$ is clearly continuous, so it maps $Sp(1)$ into a connected component of $O(3)$. But being a homomorphism of groups it has to map the identity of $Sp(1)$ to the identity of $O(3)$, therefor $\rho (Sp(1))$ will be contained in the identity component of $O(3)$, which is just $SO(3)$ as you observed.

Comment: is there an algebraic way of showing that no reflection can be written as a value of $\rho$?

Comment: I've never seen one, but here's an approach. Let $g\in Sp(1)$ be an element which gets mapped to a reflection. Then $\rho(g) ^2=I$, where $I$ denotes the identity of $O(3)$. But then $I=\rho(g)^2=\rho(g^2)$. Therefore $g^2 \in ker(\rho)$ and you can check that $ker(\rho)=\{I,-I\}$. Now maybe you have to exploit the accidental isomorphism $Sp(1)=SU(2)$; a direct computation shows that if $g^2=I$ then $g=I$ or $g=-I$ and in both cases $\rho(g)=I$. Then you have to deal with the case $g^2=-I$.

Comment: In this case $g$ is skewhermitian and thus has imaginary diagonal (as an element of $SU(2)$). It has order $4$ but I don't think a direct computation would work here, since there should be some non trivial cyclic subgroups of order $4$ inside $SU(2)$. So if one wants to stick to algebra then maybe he has to observe something different.

Comment: interesting remarks. i think it would be easier to think of $\operatorname{Sp}(1)$ as the quaternions of unit $1$, $\ker(\rho)=\{1,-1\}$, and solve $g^2=-1$. what we want to show is that $g$ only gets mapped to $I$ or rotations by $\pi$

Comment: But why does $\rho$ map $Sp(1)$ onto $SO(3)$?

Comment: Should I ask that in its own post?