# On homomorphisms of the compact symplectic group

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

Each $q$ in the symplectic group $Sp(1)$, defines an operator on the imaginary quaternions:

$\rho(q):\operatorname{Im}\mathbb{H} \rightarrow \operatorname{Im}\mathbb{H}$ by $\rho(q)(x)=qx\bar{q}$

We can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353967/sp1-and-so3-locally-isomorphic-trouble-with-part-of-proof) that $\rho:Sp(1) \rightarrow O(3)$ is a group homomorphism, and the image of the symplectic group $\rho[Sp(1)]$ is a subset of the special orthogonal group $SO(3)$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585372/question-about-the-proof-of-s3-mathbbz-2-cong-so3/585397#585397) we see that that $\rho$ maps $Sp(1)$ onto $SO(3)$

Is there an isomorphism of Lie groups from $Sp(1)$ onto the orthogonal group $O(3)$? Since $\ker(\rho)=\mathbb Z_2$, can we compose $\rho$ with a suitable reflection or a change of orientation for half of the unit quaternions to achieve such an isomorphism?

Are $Sp(1)$ and $O(3)$ isomorphic as topological groups? Are they at least isomorphic as groups or homeomorphic as topological spaces?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To see why $\rho $ is onto, see:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585372/question-about-the-proof-of-s3-mathbbz-2-cong-so3/585397#585397

Comment: The kernel is all $q \in \mathbb H$ lying in the center. So $q\in \mathbb R \subset \mathbb H$ and $Sp(1) \cap \mathbb R = \{\pm 1\}$. $Sp(1)$ is not isomorphic to $O(3)$. $O(3)$ is not connected while $Sp(1) \cong \mathbb S^3$ is connected.

Comment: Thank you, John. What do you mean "the center?"

Comment: Center in the sense of algebra: $C(\mathbb H) = \{q\in \mathbb H: \ qx = xq\ \ $for all $x\in \mathbb H\}$ (and as $q\in Sp(1)$, $q\bar q = 1$)

Comment: @Ṃųỻịgǻňạcểơửṩ FYI, there's a dedicated `\operatorname` command for these situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for clarity, the group called $\operatorname{Sp}(1)$ here is just the group $U(1,\Bbb H)$ of unit quaternions (I'm not personally used to see Sp followed by an odd index).

The morphism $\rho:U(1,\Bbb H)\to O(3,\Bbb R)$ has kernel $\{1,-1\}$ of order $2$, and image $SO(3,\Bbb R)$ of index$~2$, but that does not mean that $ U(1,\Bbb H)$ is isomorphic to $O(3,\Bbb R)$. Indeed it cannot be since $SO(3,\Bbb R)$, being a connected index $2$ subgroup, is necessarily a connected component of $O(3,\Bbb R)$, while $U(1,\Bbb H)$ is itself connected. And the same argument shows that the cannot even be a section (right inverse) $f:SO(3,\Bbb R)\to U(1,\Bbb H)$ of $\rho$, since its image having index $2$ would have to be a connected component of $U(1,\Bbb H)$, but cannot.

A simple purely algebraic argument that $U(1,\Bbb H)$ is not isomorphic to $O(3,\Bbb R)$ is that $-1\in U(1,\Bbb H)$ can be written as the square of an other element (in infinitely many many ways) but $-I\in O(3,\Bbb R)$ (the unique non identity central element) cannot. Or somewhat more generally, in $U(1,\Bbb H)$ every element is a square (as it lies in an $\Bbb R$-subalgebra of$~\Bbb H$ isomorphic to$~\Bbb C$) so there are no nontrivial group morphisms $U(1,\Bbb H)\to\{1,-1\}$, but one has $\det:O(3,\Bbb R)\to\{1,-1\}$ which is surjective.

Comment: Thank you, mr. Leeuwen. Your answer is helpful. But if we forget the topology of the groups can we make $U(1,\mathbb H)$ isomorphic to $O(3,\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @Student: No, see my addition.